# How to display an already selected Angular Component mat-chip?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I would like to display a list of mat-chips that are already selected when user opens up the dialog based on the 'available' property.

Here is my HTML template:

```
`
```

```
  <mat-chip-list formControlName="sizes" #chipList [multiple]="true" [selectable]="true">

      <mat-chip #chipRef
        *ngFor="let gearSize of gearItemForm.controls['sizes'].value"
        [ngClass]=""
        [selected]="gearSize.available"  
        (click)="gearSize.available = !gearSize.available; onSelectedChipSize()"  
        [color]="gearSize.color">{{ sizeEnum[gearSize.size] }}, {{ gearSize.available }}  
      </mat-chip>

    </mat-chip-list>

      <input
        matInput
        formControlName="sizes"
        placeholder="Gear sizes..."
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        style="display: none;"
        class="gear-size-label"
      >

    <mat-error *ngIf="gearItemForm.get('sizes').invalid && gearItemForm.get('sizes').touched">Please select a size</mat-error>

  </mat-form-field>     
`
```

Whenever `gearSize.available` is `true` or `false`, it does not effect the `[selected]` property on the `mat-chip` and the chip component is never selected. User always has to physically change the color of the chip manually. How can I display an already selected `mat-chip` list if the `available` property is `true`?

Comment: This should definitely work. It works with the example on material.angular.io if you use true or false in `selected` property: https://stackblitz.com/angular/lvnlvnkergx?file=app%2Fchips-overview-example.html

Comment: so instead of just having the selected as a directive attribute, can you pass it a function that evaluates to true or false? I have an object that whose property may change, depending which item you select. I wonder if my property binding is just wrong

Comment: There's nothing wrong in that piece of code, at least. The selected state will change according to `gearSize.available`. But there are things that can prevent the template to show the changes (`OnPush` strategy, for instance).

Comment: let me update my template in the question. i think it has to do with the fact that I am using mat-form-field. The issue lies with the 'formControlName=sizes' once I take that out, it works as expected

Comment: Sure thing. You must put the control in input and it won't contain the list of chips added (you must control it in a parallel way).

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Just to check, are you trying to display the list of selected `mat-chips` that the user has probably previously selected/input via that `input` with the formControlName of `sizes?` I guess you are doing so by loading it from an external source when the component is initialised?

Comment: Yes that is precisely what I am trying to do. This will be loaded from a database

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a basic POC to verify your need. This is how the implementation looks like.
In the component I have got an array of objects like this:

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';

 /**
  * @title Basic chips
  */
 @Component({
    selector: 'chips-overview-example',
    templateUrl: 'chips-overview-example.html',
    styleUrls: ['chips-overview-example.css'],
  })
  export class ChipsOverviewExample {

     gearItem = [{'item': 'gearItem1', value: true},{'item': 'gearItem2', value: 
                 false}];
  }
```

And then in the html:

```
   <mat-chip-list>
      <mat-chip *ngFor="let gearSize of gearItem" [selected]="gearSize.value"></mat-chip>
   </mat-chip-list>
```

This seems to be working fine and a working stackblitz link is here: [MatchipImplementation](https://angular-a1ucfc.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: I think the problem lies with how I am syncing the array with the form. I just noticed that previously I had a basic `FormControl` that i then shoved an array into. This worked fine for what I was doing at the time, however now it is breaking. I tried this but it still did not work. `this.gearItemForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.fb.control(name, Validators.required),
      price: this.fb.control(price, Validators.required),
      sizes: this.fb.array(sizes, this.requireSize()),
      inStock: this.fb.control(inStock),
      images: this.fb.array(images)
    })`